# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'face_recognition'

Tags: python, pip, face-recognition

```
import face_recognition

image = face_recognition.load_image_file("My_Image.png")
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image)
print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)
```

When I run above code, I've found following error message.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "sample.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import face_recognition

And I've checked that I've found following error message when I've installed `face_recognition` library.

`pip install face_recognition`

```
  RuntimeError:
  *******************************************************************
   CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
  *******************************************************************


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib, Pillow, numpy, face-recognition-models, face-recognition
```

> Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/lj/cyczw6r164b5f3q1dvmbbkfh0000gn/T/pip-install-gk35rom0/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/var/folders/lj/cyczw6r164b5f3q1dvmbbkfh0000gn/T/pip-record-3enjhgfq/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/lj/cyczw6r164b5f3q1dvmbbkfh0000gn/T/pip-install-gk35rom0/dlib/

My python version is `Python 3.7.1` and pip is `pip 19.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)`

Comment: Is Cmake installed? Also I am assuming Ubuntu?

Comment: Install Cmake then do `pip3 install face_recognition`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install Cmake with:

`sudo apt install cmake`

And for python3 don't use `pip` alone, use `pip3` to install future python3 modules:

`pip3 install face_recognition`

Comment: still not working even I've installed `cmake` and `pip3 install face_recognition`

Comment: got it, there is credential required to install `pip3 install face_recognition`.

Comment: facing similar kind of problem, Please can you share complete steps

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue, but then it solved through following steps:

Step 1: Download Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 or newer (check if build tools are enough).

Step 2: Download cmake (pip install cmake)

Step 3: Install dlib (pip install dlib)

Step 4: Install face-recognition (pip install face-recognition)

But install it in specific environment that will be used later for face_recognition code (In conda: activate environment name).

Reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSQAXMgwLFo

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who still found error when installing this step, I will give a brief requirements for your system.

1. Python3.9 [**the most important**]
2. Download dlib ([this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Billyas/python-dlib/master/dist/dlib-19.23.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl))

Next, after the above requirement fulfilled, do this.

1. pip install cmake
2. pip install dlib-19.23.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
3. pip install opencv-python
4. pip install face_recognition

Bonus, in my case, I got error with the pillow library so you need to reinstall it, using these steps.

1. pip uninstall pillow
2. pip install Pillow

Well, I hope this will help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
pip install CMake==3.22.2
pip install dlib==19.18.0
pip install face_recognition
```